# Are banks in the US obligated to opt you out from Visa Account Updater?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

According to a somewhat [related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242906/how-does-shutterstock-keep-getting-my-latest-debit-card-number):

> Shutterstock subscribes to Account Updater, and gets updated copies of
> your card info when it expires or is replaced.
>
> VAU is Visa's version; more info is in a fact sheet here. MasterCard
> calls their version Account Billing Updater. American Express calls
> their version Cardrefresher. Payment processors will often aggregate
> multiple Card Brand's versions into a single service for Merchants.
>
> It is theoretically possible to opt out of Account Updater, going
> through your bank to do so. It's one of those 'you have to know in
> order to ask' type of things, and I'm betting the ease of doing so
> varies from bank to bank.

I called my bank (Bank of America) and they're saying opting out of this is not possible, even going as far as hinting that I'm trying to do this so that I could scam merchants. Is there an obligation on the banks side to opt me out of this "helpful" service?

Comment: I've never heard of this.  (ESPN definitely doesn't isn't subscribed to it, from the chain of emails complaining that they couldn't process my renewal.)  As far as scamming merchants... that's arrant nonsense.  Merchants know when your card expires; if they're sending you stuff on an expired card, they're the stupid ones.

Comment: @RonJohn the New York Times pulled this trick on me. I've thought I could automatically stop my subscription since I replacedy card but they sneakily charged me $4 on the new card. Not a lot of money, but its a matter of principle.

Comment: Oh I completely agree that it's sneaky and underhanded.  I've just never heard of it...

Comment: I've actually been working with this at my day job.  I can't tell you _how_ to do it, but I do know there's an indicator in the updates that the merchant gets which means "Cardholder opted out".  It's either something that's allowed on a bank-by-bank basis, or the CS rep you got just didn't know about it.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. Thanks for alerting us to this, @JonathanReez ....  I am going to try to opt out today ....

Comment: What could be a legitimate reason to not want that feature? Aside from being to lazy to cancel a subscription?

Comment: @Aganju matter of principle. I always treated the card number as secret information that I and I alone will share with merchants whom I trust. Otherwise yes - getting a new card has always been a way to stop using services I don't really need. I.e. in this iteration I've dropped NYT (who pulled the Updater trick), Spotify, a VPN service and a couple of other random subscriptions. No fraud whatsoever as they were all month to month with no long term commitment.

Comment: @JonathanReez Cancelling a service by changing your card number is problematic.  The merchant will generally try to charge the card a few times before giving up, and they may have continued providing you service during that time - at which point you _do_ owe them payment, since you never notified them you wished to cancel. (A service which just shuts down your account on renewal day if they fail to charge your card would just turn you off.) On the other hand, if you tried to cancel and use changing the card number as a way to ensure that it stops, then that's fine.

Comment: @Bobson in any case that's between me and the merchant. The bank shouldn't be meddling with my personal contracts. As for *and they may have continued providing you service during that time* => I vehemently disagree. Its their problem, not mine. Disable the service as soon as payment falls through, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Well, I've got worse news for you, then. I believe that if the recurring payment is set up correctly (and the rules on what that means have changed in the last few years), then your bank may choose to continue to honor those recurring charges against it, even after you've gotten a new card... _without_ the merchant even needing to get the new card number.  Effectively, the payment request says "I am authorized to make this charge because of <this> previous charge which the cardholder authorized". Still up to the bank to approve it or not, but the intent is that there's a chain.

Comment: @Bobson I'm switching to Privacy.com one-off cards from now on to combat this. What a horrible anti-consumer policy, given that there's no opt-out.

Comment: @JonathanReez - The opt-out is to tell the merchant to cancel the recurring charge, and complain to your bank if they don't.   [Here's an article about it](https://meawallet.com/how-recurring-payments-improve-with-network-tokens/).  The thing to remember is that the credit card networks are _not_ on your side:  They make money when your card is charged, and when you fail to pay the bill on time.  _Anything_ that makes it easier to make a payment is a good thing, provided it doesn't open up more opportunity for fraud (and card usage fraud is much more common than merchant charging fraud).

Comment: @Bobson for example to cancel an NYT subscription they demand that you call them or use their webchat - there's no convenient "disable" button, even though they're happy to take your money without a phonecall. I consider that fraudulent enough that I don't want to bother canceling the service on their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted my bank (Bank of America) over both email and phone with no luck - it seems that there's no way to opt out of this service. A Google search for "[visa account updater opt out](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22visa%20account%20updater%22%20%22opt%20out%22)" shows that credit unions often offer an opt out, but not major banks.

However there's a neat solution - [Privacy.com](https://privacy.com/home) virtual one-off cards. Each merchant gets its own unique card and you can cancel it at any time, without the "account updater" getting in the way. If you value the ability to fully control your finances, this might be the way forward. I wish they allowed fully anonymous usage funded by, say, Bitcoin - but so far that's the best I could find on the market. If you live in the EU, you can use [disposable Revolut cards](https://blog.revolut.com/en-us/enhancing-safety-with-revolut-disposable-virtual-cards/) for the same purpose.

Comment: Privacy.com is US only, so it's unfortunately useless to the most of the world

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh updated with an EU solution. Not sure about other regions.