# How can I avoid overdraft fees while moving all of my funds to a new bank?

Tags: banking

I called my bank to close my account. The sequence of events they told me was required is:

- Transfer all of my funds to the other bank (makes sense).
- Wait up to 2 business days for the transfer to complete.

But when I asked:

- If I transfer all of my funds from my account and some automated monthly subscription I've forgotten to cancel comes through, I'll be charged an overdraft fee.
- Can I suspend all new transactions on the account? No.
- Is there any solution for this or way I can safely empty my account without worry about about incurring overdraft fees? No.

Obviously the best solution would be to carefully track all of your monthly subscriptions and move them to the new account, but I've been a bit frivolous with these (Netflix, Hulu, Youtube, HBO, Amazon, Apple TV, Apple Music, Vimeo, Github, the list goes on and on) and have so many, I'm tempted to use this as an opportunity to let them all fail to renew and only update billing for the ones I actually notice not having anymore.

I'm just a little surprised that I'm not allowed to suspend charges on my own bank account, especially after telling the bank I want to close the account.

Edit: Now that I realize it matters (jealous glance at Europeans), I am in the US.

Comment: What country are you in? For example, in the UK, the [Current Account Switching Service](https://www.currentaccountswitch.co.uk/) should take care of most of this automatically.

Comment: Every time I've ever switched banks, they've specifically asked me to verify that there are no outstanding transactions.

Comment: This is also one reason why I always push payments from my bank, rather than authorize a 3rd party to withdraw payment.

Comment: "I'm just a little surprised that I'm not allowed to suspend charges on my own bank account, especially after telling the bank I want to close the account.", Boy that would be great wouldn't it? I could go around charging purchases and paying with checks and then just tell the bank not to honor any of them! Free stuff! Do you see the problem?

Comment: Note that ‘letting them fail’ is **not** silently canceling your contracts, you still owe them, they just have to come after you (which you will finally pay for in addition)

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant That's no different from creating a check with an invalid bank account number, though.  Perfectly possible to do.

Comment: @TripeHound U.S. unfortunately.

Comment: @Aganju right but most of my monthly subscriptions are not contracts. I am carefully tracking those to avoid any collections or hits to my credit.

Comment: Can they really charge you overdraft fees after your bank account is closed and you are no longer a customer?

Comment: @TripeHound: it does! I've used it twice this year, works like a charm. Thankfully America is free from such overbearingly destructive government interference, giving J.Todd the liberty to figure this out themself and pay a usefully-educational financial penalty for each and every mistake.

Comment: @TripeHound It may have improved but I ran into trouble with a direct debit not getting switched properly (by BT).  It actually ended up being quite expensive because we got into arrears - and neither bank was apparently to blame  so the guarantee didn't help

Comment: @Aganju "Note that ‘letting them fail’ is not silently canceling your contracts, you still owe them, they just have to come after you (which you will finally pay for in addition)" All the contracts listed as examples in the question will be cancelled just fine by stopping payments. The one time I resorted to stopping payments to quit a contract my bank actually reverted some of my payments (because they messed up stopping the payments on time and then overcompensated) and even then it stopped the contract without further consequences.

Comment: If you say so, @Nobody ... feel free to do it. Legally, the contracts say different (did you ever read them?), but they are probably too lazy to go after you. It's still not legal, but sure, if someone gets sued, they can ask you to jump in for them.

Comment: @Aganju Sure I read the contracts, that's how I knew I could force my bank to stop the payments. To think that any of the mentioned companies (Netflix, Hulu, Youtube, HBO, Amazon, Apple TV, Apple Music, Vimeo, Github) would sue you over a monthly payment or two is absurd.

Comment: @gerrit - what are they going to do, bill me? Seriously though, apparently [you "go on a list"](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/146809/67482).

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Well, that's how SDD mandates work in Europe. When you setup an SDD mandate you can remove it at any time and the automatic withdrawals stop. Even better: you can report any withdrawal as invalid for up to 8 weeks after the withdrawal date and the banks will honor the dispute immediately no question asked. This however does not mean you don't own the money, it simply means they will have to go after you in some other way, and they can obviously cut/reduce the service you should be paying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a very US-centric question and answer.

### Don't bounce payments. Use credit cards for that.

> and some automated monthly subscription I've forgotten to cancel comes through, I'll be charged an overdraft fee

Because bank accounts require more personal responsibility than credit cards.  The overdraft fee is the "lite" punishment for bouncing charges.  The "heavy" punishment is a 7-year ban from using banking - you become one of "the unbanked".  If you wonder who uses those weird pink neon check cashing stores, it is the unbanked.

The punishments are fierce because *bouncing checks is serious business*.  Also, the bank is providing you a service - for that $39 fee they're giving you overdraft protection in many cases, paying the charge *anyway* and letting your account go negative for a few days.

You should treat your bank accounts with a certain amount of respect and fear.

**For this use-case (e.g. monthly subscriptions), you should be using credit cards, not bank account debit**.  Credit cards are specifically designed to use the way you are trying to use it - charges that will have no consequence to you if they are declined.

Further, credit cards provide *vastly better* consumer protections in all sorts of ways, which suit themselves well to a person like you who isn't necessarily always on top of everything.  (like me too, no judging here).

Even if you don't have good credit, seek out a deposit-type credit card, where you give the bank $500 cash and they give you a credit card with a $500 credit limit.  *Don't use "prepaid visa/mastercard gift cards" like you buy at the checkout lane at grocery stores; they have many gotchas and most subscription services won't accept them anyway*.

### "Unsubscribing by breaking payment methods" is a dumb idea.

Because most banks and credit cards will do their level best to make sure trusted services like Netflix are able to continue charging, even with obsolete card info.  Why? It saves them millions in customer support costs.

**If you want to unsubscribe, the absolute best way is to log onto the service, and use the "unsubscribe" feature** (at the risk of stating the obvious).  It also helps to delete all your payment methods.

### How to untangle the mess

*Actually, I'm doing that right now, because I am wrapping up an estate which has many automatic deposits and debits in/out of its bank accounts.  Easier for you, you have all the passwords to those services lol.*

The key thing, I'm guessing you either trash all your bank statements or did paperless and never look at the statements.  OK, it's time to look at them.

- Log into your online account at the bank (I gather you have one; if not call bank CS and create one).
- Pick the checking account in question.
- Look for "Statements".
- This will give you a list of all your monthly statements going back 10 years.
- Click the most recent statement, grab a note pad and write down every charge.  Especially if it looks like a subscription service.
- Click the previous statement, write down any charges you haven't already seen.
- Lather rinse repeat, with every statement going back 13 months.  That will catch *annual* subscriptions.

For each of those services:

- Log in.
- Go to "account / payment methods".
- ADD a credit card payment method.
- *Very important:* DELETE your bank account payment method.

You need to delete the bank method, because if your primary is declined, many will automatically try every other payment method in the system until they find one that works. Deleting the payment method is the only way to stop them doing that.

### How to close a bank account

There is no law that says to open an account, you must close another.  You can have as many as you want.  In most cases there is a monthly fee, but that is the only downside.

So, you move most of your money out of the old account into your new account, and start doing all your business out of the new account.

But leave enough money in the old account to cover a couple months of your automatic debits. If there's a minimum to avoid fees in the old account, and you can afford to leave that amount there plus a bit for charges, then do so.

Labor as I described above to identify and move all your periodic charges.

Check your old bank's statement every month.  When you get 1 statement that was *quiescent* (no activity except for a monthly fee), then go into the bank, see a banker, close the account and take it in cash.

Comment: This seems to be a very US-centric answer. In Europe, bank accounts require vastly _less_ personal responsibility. 7 year ban for an overdraft? A European bank that would propose that would lose its license over such blatant consumer abuse. Of course, with electronic payments instead of checks, the whole notion of a bounced check is also laughable.

Comment: The whole idea of virtual credit cards are about making "Unsubscribing by breaking payment methods" easier when the vendor is not letting you unsubscribe easily.

Comment: @MSalters it's not a 7 year ban as punishment for overdrafts. it's a punishment for check fraud.

Comment: Just to note, there are some places that are not as easy to "unsubscribe" to (think professional resource subscriptions) and many of them are behind the times, require emails or even snail mail letters to cancel an expensive service which they can "conveniently" claim they received after a deadline in order to ding you for an extra month.  These are not always obvious before the fact.

Comment: A failed charge on a debit card is not check fraud. It's the same as a failed charge on a credit card. From the merchant's perspective they're the same: both Visa/MC.

Comment: @R.. That doesn't work for an EFT direct debit.  Only works if you have a debit card set up as Visa-Mastercard (which the vast majority are), in which case yeah, they follow the Visa-Mastercard rules with no-consequence declines.

Comment: In Europe, I would say exactly the opposite - *never* give a "continuing credit card authority" - the only way you can stop it against the debitor's will is cancel the credit card.
With a UK Direct Debit, you can withdraw permission to debit at any time.
Within the last few years, it has also become possible in France to establish a whitelist of authorised debitors.

Comment: @MSalters It's a 7-year ban for overdrawing *and then letting the situation get out of control*. Because that case is indistinguishable from check fraud.  For instance, Goober is abandoning an account, which is then overdrawn by unwanted charges. Since Goober is leaving that bank anyway, Goober just ignores the situation and does not dispute the charges or pay them or the overdraft fees.  To Goober it's not fraud, but to the bank it is.  Keep in mind "overdraft protection" is very popular here, where the bank covers the overdrawn charge up to ~$1000. Some crooks game that.

Comment: @bunyaCloven Yeah, and that's why a lot of subscription services  will not accept "cash resgister aisle type" Visa gift cards. Companies that make unsubscribe hard tend to be shady in the first place, e.g. porn sites.  Linking an EFT to them is madness, that's what credit cards are for. Because the correct answer for those is a chargeback. A chargeback hits the merchant very hard in the face.

Comment: @MSalters and you're correct, it's a very US-centric answer, *but then, it's a very US-centric **question***.

Comment: **in cash** - I ain't waiting three days for nothing, get your little sponge out and start counting... and we're done here. kthxbye. (any more info on this 'blacklist' - just credit score stuff, or is it underhanded?)

Comment: Great answer. 1. From a lot of the comments, I've decided to move to Europe. 2. Once I tring to "wing it" unexpected charges did come through and I went into a deficit. I initiated a bank-to-bank transfer but it was too slow. I went to my bank to speak to a real person about this and was advised to wait for the moment there are no pending charges and either use the Zelle service to instantly deposit the deficit to zero and call to immediately close the account, or come to the bank with cash to fix the deficit and immediately close the account. This worked.

Comment: Also as another answer indicated, the info my bank's support personnel gave me was wrong. When I went to my bank's physical location I was told if I had not gone into a deficit I could have requested to close the account and the bank would have sent me a check with the remaining balance. The only requirement was nothing pending at that moment.

Comment: @J.Todd Yeah, Zelle's terms & conditions put you at too much of a disadvantage in fraud disputes. It's no risk to leave a little money in the account until things quiet down. **The bank won't steal it**, it's your money. If you do nothing to claim it for years, it *escheats* to the state, meaning the state holds it for you.  You file some paperwork with the state, and they mail you a check for the amount + interest.

Comment: The recommendation at the end of this answer (move most money out, transition all payments, then close the account) is great, but I think a lot of the rest is tangential and doesn't really need to be there.

Answer (score 21):

> Obviously the best solution would be to carefully track all of your
> monthly subscriptions and move them to the new account, but I've been
> a bit frivolous with these (Netflix, Hulu, Youtube, HBO, Amazon, Apple
> TV, Apple Music, Vimeo, Github, the list goes on and on).

What I would do is move most of the money to the new account. Keep enough in the old account to cover a month or two of these monthly subscriptions. Then use the next 60 days to transfer the billing to either a credit card or the new bank account.

You should also check the old account to see if there were any you forgot. Every time one is pulled from the old account, go online and switch it to the new payment method.

If it turns out you underestimated the amount of monthly charges, you may have to move money back to the old account.

You will still have to look at the bank transactions for the last year or two to look for two other things:

- Annual charges for some things. This can be from Amazon Prime, or your auto insurance.
- Things that pull funds from your bank account on an irregular schedule. This can be used to replenish funds on the loyalty card from the coffee shop, or the subway/commuter train.

To make the search easier, most banks allow you to download all your transactions into a spreadsheet. Searching inside the spreadsheet should be easier.

> I'm just a little surprised that I'm not allowed to suspend charges on
> my own bank account, especially after telling the bank I want to close
> the account.

We have had questions about this. People are amazed when a cancelled bank account springs back to life when an unexpected transaction arrives. Of course what you want to have happen is the bank to reject the transaction. But the impact is that you will have the potential embarrassment of the transaction being denied. and the possibility that the vendor will hit you with a service charge for the denied transaction.

Comment: On your last point, wouldn't it make sense to let the customer have the choice? I'm certainly tracking any services that I'm under contract for (cellphone, internet, rent, power, etc), typically services which you pay for after first using, which would otherwise go to collections. I think it's intuitive for a person to think they should have the power to shut down activity on their bank, with the understanding they they will need to pay anyone they're under contract with, or who they wrote checks to. It's not like the 3rd party doesn't have collections / credit reporting agencies as recourse.

Comment: @J.Todd Report your debit card as "lost" so all of those subscriptions will just fail.

Comment: @Turbo Reporting a card as lost won't necessarily stop recurring charges. Even if you get a new card, merchants who participate in services such as Visa Account Updater may automatically receive your new credit card details, unless you've opted out.

Comment: @Turbo that won't work.  When you report a card lost/stolen, and the bank issues you a new card, **for all known/trusted recurring chargers (like Netflix), they allow the charges to continue anyway** (and I presume they share your new CC info).   This saves both the bank and the charger *hundreds of thousands* of customer support calls - we're talking dozens of CS staff headcount, millions of dollars.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Really? That's not my experience at all, it's always such a headache to redo them all. I was unaware of the "Visa Account Updater", though. I recently got a replacement card, not even a different card number, but a different expiration date/CCV code and everything needed to be redone.

Comment: @Turbo See [my answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/98730/35567) to [How can a retailer automatically get details of my new payment cards](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/98728/35567) for a little more on Visa/Mastercard updater programs. Retailers have to subscribe to the programs, so presumably some will, some won't.

Answer (score 4):

I'm skeptical of the information your bank gave you.

If your account has a branch/physical location, I would suggest just going there and physically closing your account. They'll give you a check on the spot for your balance, and your business relationship with them will be terminated. Any further charges against that account will be declined. You'll be liable to those creditors for any declined-payment fees, but you certainly won't face a fee from the bank.

I don't have experience with closing internet-only accounts, but I'd be surprised if they don't also offer you the option to close your account on the spot and mail you a check (for free) or wire the funds elsewhere (for a fee). Waiting for the check will take some time, but the wire transfer should be practically immediate. I do agree that you probably don't want to do an ACH transfer in this situation -- it potentially takes too long, and the account you're closing probably has to be active through all of it.

Option 2)

- Open another account at the same bank. Take care that the new account isn't set up to provide overdraft protection for the old one.
- Transfer all your funds there (this should be instantaneous because it's the same bank).
- Close the original account -- you're now protected from any recurring charges.
- At your leisure, transfer all the money from your new account to the new bank.
- Close your temporary account.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care about retaining some subscriptions and/or you're sure that whoever you set up autopay with will have a grace period to permit you to fix your payment option, you can open another account in your existing bank, move all your money there and once money are moved - which should be really fast, like a matter of minutes for most of the U.S. banks, close your old account which should also be relatively quick.

Then you can transfer money from your just opened temporary account to the new bank and update all your autopay subscriptions with the new payment option.

That way you wouldn't incur overdraft fees while also eventually discovering everyone who you set up autopay with. Everyone who tries to withdraw money from the closed account will get a reject. I did exactly the above with one of my accounts and I didn't have any issues. It obviously won't work in situations when you try to pay with the check associated with the old account - in that case you'd likely face a fee, but it wouldn't be an overdraft fee, rather a standard check deposit rejection fee.

Answer (score -4):

I would explore the business relationship between the two banks. Perhaps opening a specific type of account at Bank B (your future bank) will have some positive network effect back to Bank A (which you are leaving). This could be favorable to any debt obligation you have to Bank A. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Keith, welcome. I downvoted b/c I'm not at all familiar with what you're suggesting. What is a "positive network effect?" Maybe a concrete/real-world example would help. If that example also spelled out how such a business relationship would prevent overdraft fees such that you answered OP's question, all the better :)